# css selector to identify adjacent element with same class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a css selector to highlight adjacent last two element with same class

In below code first 3 and  last 2 element have same class.
But i want to highlight `Two, Threee` and `Six, Seven`

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the only element with the class a that you don't want to highlight is the first one:

```
.a:not(:first-of-type) {
    color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
li:first-child ~ .a {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the `<li>`s with the `nth-child` selector

```css
ul li:nth-child(2), 
ul li:nth-child(3), 
ul li:nth-child(6), 
ul li:nth-child(7) { color: #a00; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Or just ignore the first class `.a` element:

```css
ul li.a:not(:first-of-type) { color: #a00; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

> highlight adjacent last two element with same class

The following selector is what you need:

```
.a:nth-last-child(2),
.a:nth-last-child(2) + .a {
  ...
}
```

To prove that it works as expected, here's a demo with two unordered lists. See how only the first one is affected because it has two adjacent elements with the same class at the end..

```css
.a:nth-last-child(2),
.a:nth-last-child(2) + .a {
  color: blue;
  background: #cce5ff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li class="a">Nine</li>
</ul>
```

---

**OTHER SELECTORS:**

---

**Selects the first two elements with the given class and the adjacent last two, inside a parent element.**

```css
.a:nth-child(2),
.a:nth-child(3),
.a:nth-last-child(2),
.a:nth-last-child(2) + .a {
  color: blue;
  background: #cce5ff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li class="a">Eight</li>
  <li class="a">Nine</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Selects all the elements with the given class, except the first one, inside a parent element.**

```css
.a:not(:first-child) {
  color: blue;
  background: #cce5ff;
}
/*
    Works the same as .a:not(:first-child) 
*/

.a:not(:nth-child(1)) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li class="a">Eight</li>
  <li class="a">Nine</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Selects the 2nd, 3rd, 6th and 7th elements with the given class, if their child node is equal to that of the selector.** *(Notice how it doesn't work for the second unordered list.)*

```css
.a:nth-child(2),
.a:nth-child(3),
.a:nth-child(6),
.a:nth-child(7) {
  color: blue;
  background: #cce5ff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="a">Six</li>
  <li class="a">Seven</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a">One</li>
  <li class="a">Two</li>
  <li class="a">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li class="a">Eight</li>
  <li class="a">Nine</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```css
.a {
  background: yellow;
}
 
.a:first-child {
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li class="a">One</li>
      <li class="a">Two</li>
      <li class="a">Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li class="a">Six</li>
      <li class="a">Seven</li>
    </ul>
```